# $ moves caret past last character

Tags: normal-mode

This is the starting situation:

[image]

Now I press `$`:

[image]

Now I press `i`:

[image]

Now I press `Esc`:

[image]

Why did the `$` move past the end of the line?

Comment: Do you have `set virtualedit` in your .vimrc? If not, does this behaviour
persist when you do `vim -u NONE your_test_file`?

Comment: From the movement of the cursor on `i` I would guess you have a tab character at the end of the line.

Comment: If Jurgen is right and the issue comes from additional whitespaces characters at the end of line, one option is to use `set list` and `set listchars=trail:.,eol:¶` to better see these unwanted characters.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer Indeed there was :)

Comment: @statox thanks for teaching me how to show them!

Comment: @robertspierre You can post an answer to your own question so that future users will find the answer more easily (or you can close with the reason "the problem was caused by a simple typographical error", up to you :) )